# Make a space between paragraph (X)HTML and CSS

Tags: html, xhtml, space, paragraph

I want space between my `<p>content</p>` tags. Not before and not after `<p>` tags. For example, my code is:

```
<div>
   <h1>A headline</h1>
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p>Some text</p>
</div>
Something
```

I don't want space between h1 and p which is done with zero margin on h1. But I don't want space after the last `<p>` tag. Is this possible without *:last-child* or some JavaScript/jQuery?

I can't set *class="last"* on the last tag because it is a CMS system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```css
p + p {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

(Although this requires a browser with better support for CSS than [IE6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6).)

Comment: Nice, I'll try that. I'm aiming for IE7+, Chrome, Safari 4+, FireFox 2+

Answer (score 4):

If you're not required to support [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) (IE6) you can use:

```css
div, h1, p { margin: 0; }
p + p { margin-top: 12px; }
```

If you need to support IE6, this is a dirty hack but it works without JavaScript:

```css
div, h1, p { margin: 0; }
h1 { margin-bottom: -12px; }
p { margin-top: 12px; }
```

The disadvantage of this method is that you can't simply use, say, 1em for the balancing margins as they have different font sizes. You can either manually adjust as required or use pixel widths.

Comment: But the problem with the last method is, that if I have a list after the h1 then they will float into eachother. I will go with IE7+.

Comment: If you can go with IE7+ then you are sorted. I'm just pointing this out for completeness because many do need to support IE6 still (sadly).

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that I wouldn't suggest doing this for all divs. I'd associate a class to put on the div where you want to do this where you know the format of the contents to avoid the situation like you mention. The same heading followed by list issue has the same problem with using the + selector.

Answer (score 2):

Set a default bottom-margin to p, then give the last tag a class with no bottom-margin.

Comment: I can't do that because the text is rendered with CMS.

Comment: OK then, how about setting margin-top to "div p" and negative margin-bottom to "div h1"?

Comment: I have not tested it but cletus solution with p + p works fine for IE7+. That will do... I hope ;)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <h1>A headline</h1>
   <p>Some text</p>
   <div class="paragraph-space"></div>
   <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I can't control the text that way. (CMS)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <h1>A headline</h1>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I can't control the text that way. (CMS)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it more browser compatible, you could also use:

```css
p { margin-top: 24px; }
h1 { margin-bottom: -24px; } /* Play with this value as necessary */
```

Negative margins will pull elements toward them. It's messier than I like, but when you are at the mercy of CMS generated code with no way to add classes, you have to be creative.